# SPSD on Sharepoint 2010 cant run because of framework 4?

Tags: powershell

I downloaded the Sharepoint Solution deployer SPSD, and I want to use it an SPSD 2010 Farm, to install jusst a wsp

But I got this error, which is pretty obvious, 2010 projects run on 3.5 framework instead of 4, but I have no idea what should I change?

```
Get-SPServer : Microsoft SharePoint is not supported with version
4.0.30319.1008 of the Microsoft .Net Runtime.
At C:\dev\username\pn\xx\xx\SolutionInstalle
\R2\Scripts\SPSD_Base.ps1:64 char:30
+            $Script:servers = Get-SPServer | Where-Object {$_.Role -ine
"Invalid" ...
+                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Share...CmdletGetServer:
   SPCmdletGetServer) [Get-SPServer], PlatformNotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell.SPCmdletGetServe
   r
```

I am adding the .bat script the SPSD uses:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
cls
REM Batchfile inspired by the launchscript of http://autospinstaller.codeplex.com

SET command=Deploy
SET verbosity=Verbose
SET type=All
SET saveEnvXml=-saveEnvXml

@TITLE -- SharePoint Solution Deployer --
FOR /F "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%i IN ('date /t') DO SET SHORTDATE=%%i-%%j-%%k
FOR /F "tokens=1-3 delims=: " %%i IN ('time /t') DO SET SHORTTIME=%%i-%%j%%k
SET LaunchedFromBAT=1
:START
:: Check for Powershell
IF NOT EXIST "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"  (
    COLOR 0C
    ECHO - "powershell.exe" not found!
    ECHO - This script requires PowerShell - install v2.0/3.0, then re-run this script.
    COLOR
    pause
    EXIT
    )
:: Check for Powershell v2.0 (minimum)
ECHO - Checking for Powershell 2.0 (minimum)...
"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" $host.Version.Major | find "1" >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 (
    COLOR 0C
    ECHO - This script requires a minimum PowerShell version of 2.0!
    ECHO - Please uninstall v1.0, install v2.0/3.0, then re-run this script.
    COLOR
    pause
    EXIT
    )
ECHO - OK.
:: Get existing Powershell ExecutionPolicy
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%x in ('"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" Get-ExecutionPolicy') do (set ExecutionPolicy=%%x)
:: Set Bypass, in case we are running over a net share or UNC
IF NOT "%ExecutionPolicy%"=="Bypass" IF NOT "%ExecutionPolicy%"=="Unrestricted" (
    ECHO - PS ExecutionPolicy is %ExecutionPolicy%, setting ExecutionPolicy to Bypass.
    "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "'-Command Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass'"
    )
GOTO LAUNCHSCRIPT
:LAUNCHSCRIPT
"%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"  -Command Start-Process "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList "'%~dp0\Scripts\SPSD_Main.ps1 -Command %command% -Type %type% -Verbosity %verbosity% %saveEnvXml%'"
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Just to confirm, your solution is built on the 3.5 framework?

Comment: confirmed, yes it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by installing .NET Framework 4.0 (uses CLR 4.0), while SharePoint 2010 requires CLR 2.0. Modify the link for the SharePoint 2010 Management Shell:

**Original:**
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe -NoExit " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\sharepoint.ps1 ' "

**New:**
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe **-Version 2.0** -NoExit " & ' C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\sharepoint.ps1 ' "

The **-Version 2.0** ensures the correct CLR to be loaded for PowerShell.

Comment: I added the SPSD .bat file, I am not sure what to change there.

Comment: Hi, the instructions are for modifying the shortcut in the Start Menu. Instead of a batch file, try creating a new shortcut and paste the entire 'New' instruction.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to find a suite of PowerShell scripts to deploy solutions. We use 4 (if all needed):

1) Deactivate and uninstall the feature:

Batch file:

```
@SET STSADM="c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\bin\stsadm.exe"
%STSADM%  -o deactivatefeature -id  19683a77-07d7-4b29-9017-7e8ab5df12ab  -url    http://url -force
%STSADM%  -o uninstallfeature  -id  19683a77-07d7-4b29-9017-7e8ab5df12ab  -force
pause
```

2) Uninstall the solution from the farm.

Batch file:

```
powershell -Command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass}" -NoExit
powershell -Command "& {.\UninstallSolutions.ps1}" -NoExit

pause
```

PowerShell (UninstallSolutions.ps1):

```
Write-Host 
# define variables for script    

# check to ensure Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is loaded
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}
if ($snapin -eq $null) {
Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

$solution = Get-SPSolution  -identity "mysolution.wsp"
write-host "Uninstalling Solution " $solution.Name;
if($solution.DeployedWebApplications.Count -gt 0) 
{
     Uninstall-SPSolution $solution –AllWebApplications -Confirm:$false;
} 
else 
{
     Uninstall-SPSolution $solution -Confirm:$false;
}
do{
      echo "Uninstalling in progress..."   
      Start-Sleep 5;
      $solution = Get-SPSolution $solution;
} while($solution.JobExists -and $solution.Deployed) 

write-host "Solution has been uninstalled: " $solution.Name;

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

3) Re-install the solution to the farm.

Batch file:

```
powershell -Command "& {Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass}" -NoExit
powershell -Command "& {.\InstallSolutions.ps1}" -NoExit

pause
```

PowerShell (InstallSolutions.ps1):

```
Write-Host 
# define variables for script

# check to ensure Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell is loaded
$snapin = Get-PSSnapin | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell'}
if ($snapin -eq $null) {
Write-Host "Loading SharePoint Powershell Snapin"
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
}

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

write-host "Adding Solution mysolution.wsp"
$sln = Add-SPSolution "C:\Solutions\mysolution.wsp"
write-host "Installing Solution " $sln.Name;
Install-SPSolution –Identity $sln.Name  -GACDeployment -Force:$true

while($sln.JobExists)
{    
    echo "Deployment in progress..."     
    start-sleep -s 5
}
write-host "Solution has been installed: " $sln.Name;

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

4) Activate the feature on the site it needs to be activated on.

Batch file:

```
@SET STSADM="c:\program files\common files\microsoft shared\web server extensions\14\bin\stsadm.exe"

%STSADM%  -o installfeature    -name  MySolution_Feature  -force
%STSADM%  -o activatefeature   -id    19683a77-07d7-4b29-9017-7e8ab5df12ab  -force -url http://url

pause
```

It is a lot of files to run, and they must be in that order, but they've been working for us for years. Also, if you switch `14` to `15` it will work with 2013.

I can't speak for why your installer isn't working. Maybe it's running some SharePoint CSOM that is written in .NET 4.0 but I'm only speculating. If the above procedure is too complex and you have access to the source code (like if it's from CodePlex) I'd suggest downloading the source, changing the framework if it isn't set to 3.5 and try re-building and using it like that. Personally here, we use the above scripts.

Comment: I know powershell very well, but I prefer SPSD to install as you dont have to worry about coding anything, you only make an xml configuration file.  The SPSD is just a lot of powershell files there are no dlls or .exe,I guess is something with the environment